# Uncertainty principle: $\Delta x \Delta p_x \ge \hbar/2$, where $p_x$ is the momentum in the $x$-direction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

I am currently studying *Diode Lasers and Photonic Integrated Circuits*, second edition, by Coldren, Corzine, and Mashanovitch. Appendix **A.1.1.1** says the following:

> In quantum mechanics, measurements are limited in accuracy by the uncertainty principle, $\Delta x \Delta p_x \ge \hbar/2$, where $p_x$ is the momentum in the $x$-direction. (In electromagnetic theory the equivalent statement is that $\Delta x \Delta k_x \ge 1/2$.)

I'm familiar with the uncertainty principle, but I'm not sure what is meant by the "$\Delta x \Delta p_x \ge \hbar/2$" part. Furthermore, what is meant by "in electromagnetic theory the equivalent statement is that $\Delta x \Delta k_x \ge 1/2$"?

I would greatly appreciate it if people would please take the time to explain this.

Comment: Since $\Delta x \Delta p_x \geq \hbar/2$ *is* the statement of the (position-momentum) uncertainty principle, could you explain what your current understanding of it is?

Comment: @J.Murray Based on what you said, I started reading the Wikipedia article for the uncertainty principle https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle and that clarified the first part. However, I'm still unsure of the electromagnetic theory part.

Comment: Given probably_someone's answer, I have rolled-back my edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you can measure position with a particular resolution $\Delta x$; in other words, suppose you can determine the position to a precision of $\pm\Delta x$. Now suppose you want to measure the momentum $p_x$. Then the uncertainty principle dictates that the **best** possible momentum resolution $\Delta p_x$ that you could theoretically achieve is given by

$$\Delta x\Delta p_x=\frac{\hbar}{2}$$

Of course, that limit is usually practically inachievable. Most likely you're not limited by the uncertainty principle, but by some characteristic of your measuring device. In that case, your momentum resolution $\Delta p_x$ will be worse (i.e. $\Delta p_x$ will be bigger) than the theoretical best. This means that we can write, in general,

$$\Delta x\Delta p_x\geq \frac{\hbar}{2}$$

For a photon, we have that $E=hf$ for energy $E$ and frequency $f$. We also have that $E=pc$, because the photon is massless, and $k=\frac{2\pi f}{c}$ from the fact that the wave travels at $c$. Combining all of this, we have that

$$pc=\frac{h}{2\pi}kc\implies \frac{p}{\hbar}=k$$

This also means that $\frac{\Delta p}{\hbar}=\Delta k$, so if we substitute in the uncertainty principle, we get the following version, which is only true for photons:

$$\Delta x\Delta k_x\geq \frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle has that $\sigma _{x}\sigma _{p}\geq {\frac {\hbar }{2}}$, where $\sigma$ is the standard deviation, and so it is a probabilistic measure. How do I reconcile this with $\Delta x\Delta p_x$?

Comment: Furthermore, the popular-science characterization of the uncertainty principle is something along the lines of "we cannot know both the position and velocity (acceleration) of a particle at the same time" (or, "the more accurately we know the position of a particle, the less accurately we know the velocity (acceleration) of the particle"). How do we reconcile this with the physics presented here (it is not clear that $\Delta x\Delta p_x \ge \frac{\hbar}{2}$ means that "we cannot know both the position and velocity (acceleration) of a particle at the same time")?

Comment: @ThePointer The resolution of your measurement can usually be approximated as the standard deviation of the measurements of a known constant value.

Comment: @ThePointer Knowing the position and the velocity of a particle at the same time, in this context, means making measurements with resolution $\Delta x=0$ and $\Delta p_x=0$ at the same time. This violates the inequality, since it is not true that $0\geq\frac{\hbar}{2}$.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you for taking the time to explain this to me.

Comment: The uncertainty principle isn't a statement of how precise your measurement is / can be. Furthermore, in $\Delta x\Delta p\geq\hbar/2$, the uncertainties are associated with standard deviations on measurements of similarly prepared states. If you have a state with some given $\Delta x$ and then make a measurement of it, then you have now changed the state, and thus you are looking at different uncertainties now. Or do you mean make a position measurement and then make repeated second position measurements to find $\Delta x$ for the state after the first position measurement?

Comment: @BioPhysicist Yes, I am aware that the uncertainties come from the intrinsic uncertainties in the properties of the quantum state, rather than peculiarities in the measuring device. I'll edit to make this especially clear; that said, the practical consequences in terms of measurement are the same - the intrinsic uncertainty in the observables imposes a limit on how precise your measurements can be.

Comment: @BioPhysicist The former; that is, when you make a first measurement for some state. Is what you are referring to here the observer effect https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_effect_(physics) ?

Comment: @BioPhysicist The scheme I envision is to take a bunch of prepared states, measure each of their positions once, and take the standard deviation of the resulting distribution (or equivalently, re-prepare the prepared state after each measurement on a single particle).

Comment: @probably_someone I agree with your most recent comment, but that is different than what is currently in the answer where you take a state, measure its position, and then measure its momentum. Of course the state after each measurement must obey the HUP, but $\Delta p$ for the state before the position measurement and $\Delta p$ for the state after the measurement will generally be different, and so will $\Delta x$ for each state. It seems like your answer combines it all into one.

Comment: "*the intrinsic uncertainty in the observables imposes a limit on how precise your measurements can be.*" I think this statement needs a lot of explanation. As you stated in your most recent comment, we are looking at standard deviations of many measurements, so how does that relate to the precision of a single measurement? Unless you are talking about relating this measurement to subsequent measurements?

Comment: @BioPhysicist We are looking at the standard deviation of a _distribution_ of measurements, that we have sampled by making the same known prepared state a bunch of times.

Comment: I agree. The language you are using in your answer though seems to talk about a single measurement and applying the HUP across multiple states instead of multiple measurements of the same state.

Answer (score 3):

To complement the good, already-posted physical answer, this one is more mathematical in nature.

The state of a quantum mechanical system can be expressed in terms of probability amplitudes which correspond to the measurable values of different observable quantities.  Explicitly, if the abstract state is called $|\psi\rangle$, then it can be expanded in the *position basis*

$$|\psi\rangle = \int d^3r \ \psi_X( x,y,z) |x,y,z\rangle$$
where $\psi_X$ is the (generally complex) position-space wavefunction. From there, $|\psi_x(x,y,z)|^2$ is a probability density function corresponding to the position observable.  The expected value of the x-coordinate, for instance, is

$$\langle x \rangle = \int d^3 r \ x|\psi_X(x,y,z)|^2$$
and the standard deviation is given by

$$\sigma_X = \sqrt{\langle x^2\rangle - \langle x \rangle^2}$$

The state can also be expanded in the momentum basis

$$|\psi\rangle = \int d^3p \ \psi_P(p_x,p_y,p_z)|p_x,p_y,p_z\rangle$$
corresponding to the momentum PDF $|\psi_P(p_x,p_y,p_z)|^2$.  The standard deviation $\sigma_P$ is defined analogously to the $\sigma_X$.

---

The key input is that $\psi_P$ can be obtained from $\psi_X$ by Fourier transform. That is,

$$\psi_P(\mathbf p) = \frac{1}{(2\pi\hbar)^{3/2}}\int d^3r \ \psi_X(\mathbf x) e^{-i\mathbf p \cdot \mathbf x/\hbar}$$

Correspondingly, there is a relationship between their standard deviations.  The computation is not too difficult, and yields the uncertainty principle as a result.  The reason electromagnetism is brought up is that the spatial part of electromagnetic [wave packets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_packet) can be written

$$u(\mathbf x) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{3/2}}\int d^3k \ A(\mathbf k) e^{-i\mathbf k \cdot \mathbf x}$$

where $u(\mathbf x)$ is the amplitude of the field at position $\mathbf x$, whereas $A(\mathbf k)$ is the amplitude corresponding to wave-vector $\mathbf k$.  Since $u$ and $A$ are related via Fourier transform, an identical mathematical argument applies.

Comment: Thanks for the additional answer. I'm confused by the way the integrals are written, because the differential term seems to be written first ( $\int d^3r$, $\int d^3p$, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}}\int dx$, $\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{3/2}}\int d^3k$). I have not seen this in mathematics. Is this some notational convention in physics, or is there something mathematical going on here that I do not understand? I do not recall such notation in mathematical analysis or probability theory.

Comment: @ThePointer There is nothing special about it, it's simply a notational difference.

Comment: Oh, ok. So the integrals are still computed in the conventional way (that is, as if the rest of the expression was within the integrals, with the differential term coming last)?

Comment: @ThePointer Yes.